# Why does Magento do duplicate URLs?

Tags: magento-1.9

For example,

http://mysite.com/magento/high-level-category/second-level-category/product-page1.html

and

http://mysite.com/magento/product-page1.html

go to the same place.

It does this for all the pages.

Duplicate URLs are bad for SEO. How do I make it so that I just get the first format of URL?

Thanks

Comment: They aren't bad for SEO if you properly are using the Canonical SEO meta tag setup in Magento System Config.

Comment: @Serpyre care to make those comments into an answer with a little description of what's necessary?

Comment: Heh, links or it didn't happen... This should be flagged as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about SEO, you should use the Canonical URL option. You could find it under:
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories & Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products.

Comment: With using the canonical tag (which Google recommends), most Magento duplicate content SEO concerns go away.

Answer (score 1):

If you want products to only be accessible under one URL then enable `system -> config -> catalog -> seo -> use categories path for product URLs -> no`.  It works this way in case you have products under multiple categories and want to differentiate between the products reached from these different paths.

EDIT: You can't just have the first format.

Comment: I presume I could do .HTACCESS rewrites anyway if I wanted.

Comment: If you don't have too many products and so it is practical, then you can just add 301 redirects via the admin panel under `catalog -> url rewrite management`

Comment: I presume I could use pattern matching and just redirect everything of the second pattern to the first.

Comment: If you have consistent enough paths then yes you could use regex in your rewrites.

Comment: Or you can use a canonical URL in all the pages echoing always the same one.

Comment: @mbalparda which is already built into Magento System Config.